# react-native-gifted-chat showing same message multiple time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm using `react-native-gifted-chat` in my react-native app. As I shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCiaZ.png) image, there is same message displayed multiple time and `message: Yes getting new msg` 's place is also varied from it's actual position.
My issue is same as [this](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/1027). Can anyone please help me to solve this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be two reasons behind it,

1) Each message should be passed a unique id, so just use `uuidv4` npm package and append it to `_id` prop of the object.

Example:

```
messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, {
              _id: uuidv4(), // or use  Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000)
              text: text,
              createdAt: new Date(),
              user: {
                _id: 2,
                name: "React Native",
                avatar: "https://placeimg.com/140/140/any"
              },
              image: attachment
            })
```

2) Second possibility could be on the gateway you are using to initiate the chat between users. So, some gateways have known issues to repeat the message multiple times. You could to string comparison each time a new message is received and pushed to the chat screen, however it is not advised to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution of my question. @Ron you are right but in my case the issue is different. I solved it by change my format of parameters. It took different format and I passed different so they conflicted each other. Here is the solution it may useful to others.

```
parse = snapshot => {
    const { timestamp: numberStamp, text } = snapshot.val();
    const { key: _id } = snapshot;
    const createdAt = moment(snapshot.val().createdAt, "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss");

     const user = { };
     var temp_data = snapshot.val()
     if(snapshot.val().name == this.state.temp_logged_name) {
         user._id = 1; 
         user.name = temp_data.name;
         user.avatar = temp_data.avatar;
     }
     const message = {
        _id,
        createdAt,
        text,
        user,
     };
     return message;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I had encountered this issue as well. I had set up `react-native-gifted-chat` on my mobile app. And at the other end I had set up a simple HTML page with a script to initialise the Websocket connection and send messages on the `onsend` event. What I had realised later that while the unique id was getting generated at the app end (because the id was being generated by the library itself), nothing of such sort existed at the other end.

Basically, this weird behaviour crops up when a unique id `_id` is missing for a message. Each message must have **at least** the following properties while executing `GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, messages)`.

```
      {
        _id: 1,
        text: 'Hello developer',
        createdAt: new Date(),
        user: {
          _id: 2
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out by simply applying the filter to the incoming message in useLayout Effect:

```js
  useLayoutEffect(() => {


    db.collection('Chats').doc(docID).collection('messages').orderBy("createdAt", "desc").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
     setMessages(
        prev => 
        
        prev
       .filter((ftr,index,self) => ftr?.user?._id !== loginUser?.id) //login user id is the current user's id you can do the same for recieved messages
        .concat
       (snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data({
         _id: doc?.id,
         user: doc.data().user,
         text: doc.data().text,
         createdAt:new Date(doc.data().createdAt),
       })
       ))





     )
   })

   
   },[])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```